# Symfony2 tutorial deprecated function

Tags: php, symfony

I am learning Symfony2 Framework, and to start things of I found this tutorial: [Tutorial](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/). Everything has been going well until I hit this issue:

in [Tutorial Part2](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/validators-and-forms.html). In Creating the form in the controller section i discover that the `getRequest()` function is deprecated and `bindRequest()` is not found in class.

These two have held me back with the tutorial and learning progress. I there any other way of constructing this controller without using these functions or are there other functions that do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this [part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/direct_submit.html) of the Symfony Documentation. It shows that you should use `handleRequest`, like so:

```
// Top of page:
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
...

// controller action
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        // ...
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // perform some action...

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('task_success'));
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

You may also find this link useful: [Handling Form Submissions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#book-form-handling-form-submissions).

**The Request as a Controller Argument**

Getting the request object in this way might be a little confusing at first, to quote the documentation:

> What if you need to read query parameters, grab a request header or
>   get access to an uploaded file? All of that information is stored in
>   Symfony's Request object. To get it in your controller, just add it as
>   an argument and type-hint it with the Request class:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function indexAction($firstName, $lastName, Request $request)
{
    $page = $request->query->get('page', 1);

    // ...
}
```

This information can be found on the [Controller Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html).

Comment: With some ajustments I go tit working just fine, but you definitly put me on the right track thx